# vba Checkbox if else condition in Subform, access

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox, subform

I have a main form with several tab controls with subforms in them. On the first tab or subform I have a "checkbox 1", which shall be:

- checked if "textbox 1" is not empty
- unchecked if "textbox 1" is empty

The code is directly put into the Class Object of "subform 1", that's why I thought I could use `Me`.

Here is my code, but I always get error messages :(

```
Private Sub Ctltextbox_1_AfterUpdate()
    If Len(Ctltextbox_1.Value) = 0 Then
        Me.checkbox_1.Value = 0
    Else
        Me.checkbox_1.Value = -1
    End If
End Sub
```

That way I am getting the

> Run-time error '2448': You can't assign a value to this object.

On the line that attempts to assign `-1` to `Me.checkbox_1.Value`.

Comment: What's the error message you get? That may help us. Also, you can always explicitly reference the subform itself.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Check the check box if the text box is not empty and uncheck when the text box is empty?

Comment: Right now with the "Me." way: You can"t assign a value to this object. It's always debugging on "Me.checkbox_1.Value= -1 ".

Comment: @Wiktor: Exactly. The code is also working this way on a mainform, but not in the subform.

Comment: I would avoid the underscore in identifier names - if you noticed, VBA uses that character to identify procedures that implement an interface or handle an event. Seems a `-1` literal isn't valid. Is there a `vbChecked` constant in scope? Have you tried `True` instead?

Comment: and `Ctltextbox_1` is on the same subform as `checkbox_1`?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried it with True/ False but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes, checkbox and textbox are on the same subform.

Comment: @ Mat's Mug: I have also tried to put the names into [] brackets instead of the underlines. Maybe I try to rename them...

Comment: Nope, renaming and deleting the spaces also doesn't help :/

Comment: Ok, I extincted the spaces by changing the names and deleted the "Ctl" expressions. Instead I have If Len(Me.textbox1.value) with the Me expression. At least it is checking now automatically, but not unchecking :/ Does anyone have an idea why its working only one way??

Comment: Could the textbox be null?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is working for me. I moved it to the Ctltextbox_1_Change action. This will call the function whenever it is changed and will catch when you have nothing in the box as well. I also changed your values to True and False.

Please try this and let me know.

```
Private Sub Ctltextbox_1_Change()
    If Len(frmSub.Ctltextbox_1.Value) = 0 Then
        frmSub.CheckBox_1.Value = False
    Else
        frmSub.CheckBox_1.Value = True
    End If
End Sub
```

you can also solve this in one line as mentioned below.

```
Private Sub Ctltextbox_1_Change()
    frmSub.CheckBox_1.Value = IIf((Len(frmSub.Ctltextbox_1.Value) = 0), False, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: This can be done on one line. Furthermore, null is important.

Comment: "Using "Me" may not work when you have multiple forms open" This is not true.

Comment: There is an even easier way :) Also, change may not be the best bet.

Comment: There is are so many different ways to accomplish the same things in code. :)

Comment: BTW Me refers to the form that the code runs in, you have a false statement.

Comment: Null is important.

Comment: Consider, `Nz(CheckB0x_1,0)` .value is redundant, it is the default.

Comment: Hello Fionnuala, I tried your modifications with Ctl (then nothing happens, if I insert/delete values in the textbox and update), Change() (nothing happens), False/True (nothing happens) and frmSub instead of Me. (get error message 424: Object required).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the simple answer is: you can not use the expression Len()= 0 for a not numeric field! So my working code for the subform is now:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_AfterUpdate()
If IsNull(Textbox1.Value) = False Then
    Me.checkbox1.Value = True
Else
    Me.checkbox1.Value = False
End If
```

`End Sub`

Thank you all for your help! :)